# poetry fails to install pyyaml with "is not a supported wheel on this platform" error

Tags: python-poetry

I have poetry project with `pyyaml` as a dependency.

Whenever I call `poetry install` I am getting this error

```
ERROR: PyYAML-6.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Running `pip` within poetry's virtualenv works just fine

```
poetry run pip install pyyaml==6.0.0 --force-reinstall
```

After this step the `poetry install` also runs fine.

What may be the problem?

I am running this code on `MacOS Monterey 12.6`, `Python 3.8.13`